# Bitbucket REST interface and GIT; how to get a log history between two tags from a branch

Tags: git, rest, api, bitbucket, commit

I am building an app to which requires all the commit comments from git commits against a branch on remote origin. Our repository is hosted on a BitBucket server and is a Git repository.

I have looked over the Bitbucket (Stash) REST api and I can bring back the git comments by browsing the commits, something like this:

```
  https://mybitbucket.local/rest/api/1.0/projects/myslug/repos/myproduct/commits?limit=1000&branch=mybranch
```

What I need now, just to make it more efficient, is a mechanism to request the content from just between two tags. Is this possible? I imagine providing two tags as parameters, like &fromTag=X&toTag=y...

I cannot find this, and the documentation is a little sparse... :(

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Bitbucket Server's "[compare/commits](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.11.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp3146256)" REST API call:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/compare/commits
```

"Gets the commits accessible from the {@code from} commit but not in the {@code to} commit."

Here's an example call against my demo server (probably need to login as user "test" with pass "test" first) that returns with 5 commits that can be seen from `a6e64f4fd0e` but are not visible from `master`:

http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/BB/repos/aui/compare/commits?from=a6e64f4fd0e&to=master&limit=100

Since you're using Bitbucket/Stash, you might be interested in my [Bit-Booster Commit Graph and More](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.bit-booster.bb/server/overview) add-on to visually verify the correct commits are being returned, [like so](http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/plugins/servlet/bb_net/projects/BB/repos/aui/commits?bb=dbfhrto&grep=true&jira=AUI-1546):

[image: Condensed Git Graph for AUI-1546]

In this case the 5 commits that match "AUI-1546" are the ones my example "commits/compare" REST API call above is returning.  You can see quite clearly on this graph how they are precisely the 5 commits that are 1.) accessible from `a6e64f4fd0e` and 2.) not accessible from `master`.